# Rundesk cannot execute local command

Tags: java, node.js, remote-access

I'm trying to interact with the nodejs Azure sdk from a CentOS installation of Rundeck.

If I try from the "run" adhoc virtual shell, I am able to after running `azure account import <mykey>` and can then also execute other Azure commands inside of jobs if I set them as Rundeck node tasks and not selecting "dispatch to nodes" in the job settings.

Trying to run the Azure sdk commands as commands to be dispatched to the node (local) fails with the error:

```
localhost1-NodeDispatch-localexec   
04:53:04    /usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
04:53:04    Failed: NonZeroResultCode: Result code was 127
```

I am not able to "jumpstart" the same environment by running `azure account import <mykey>`

I am assuming this is a permissions/environmental issue, though not sure how to fix it.

**UPDATE:**

Executing `whoami` from the same job returns `rundeck`, so I assume I will need to either modify that to execute tasks as my system user or grant permissions to get the `rundeck` user into the node environment the Azure sdk is running in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issue, I ran the local command as sudo, which also required disabling the need for tty in visudo and negating the need for sudo password for the rundeck user.

Please note that this opens many potential security holes and should not be used in production.